# Will a huge mongodb affect my Meteor application?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am going to deploy a Meteor web application that stores around 2880 records per day. I wanted to know if this somehow will affect my application's performance? I am only publishing the data of the last 24 hours to the client so that won't be a problem. I just want to know if having a big mongodb will affect the server somehow (i.e. if all those records are saved in the server's RAM instead of disk). Thank you.

Comment: 2800 records a day is peanuts. And MongoDB does not store data in RAM. You may be thinking about Redis, which is primarily a in-memory database.

Comment: this is less about the capabilities of Mongo and more about how you design your collection, use your collection, and write indices on your collection.

Comment: As @zim said, and don't forget to setup oplog.